# Executing a testfor command not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a capture the flag minicame in Minecraft 1.8.1. One of the features is automatically picking up flags when a valid player is in range. To accomplish this, I placed an armor stand inside each flag.

The goal is to get that armor stand to test for valid players (i.e. not on the same team, doesn't already have a flag, etc.) and set the block that was the banner to air. Each flag has a certain rotation value that is used to tell what team it represents - in this case, a rotation (`ry` and `rym` in the command) of 0 means the blue team. So, this command should tell all armor stands with a rotation of 0 to check for players not on the blue team who don't already have a banner.

Here's the command that isn't working: 
`execute @e[type=ArmorStand,ry=0,rym=0] ~ ~ ~ testfor @p[r=2,score_hasBanner=0,team=!blue]`

And here's the error: `Failed to execute '/testfor @p[r=2,score_hasBanner=0,team=!blue]' as Heads Up` ("Heads Up" is the custom name of the armor stand, don't worry about why)

This error tells me that the `execute` command must be working fine, meaning it's a problem with the `testfor` command. However, using the `testfor` part on its own works perfectly.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `execute` a valid command keyword? Have you added `/` at the beginning? All command require a `/` at the beginning, regardless if it's in the chat log or in a command block.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No, you don't need a slash in front of the commands in the command block - I haven't used a single one and the rest of the project works fine. `execute` is a valid command since 1.8, and I'm sure I've got the syntax right. Error is just a generic `Failed to execute '/testfor @p[r=2,score_hasBanner=0,team=!blue]' as Heads Up`

Comment: I'll add that to the question

Comment: Since the armor stand has a custom name, why aren't you using `execute @e[name=<name>...`?

Comment: Try debugging it by running the testfor command in your chat bar and see what it tells you.

Comment: @MBraedley: All the armor stands have the same name, so I needed some other way to tell them apart. Rotation was just the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: @kittycat3141: Like I said in the question, the `testfor` part works fine on its own.

Comment: @GeorgePlatko but it wouldn't be hard to give them different names. That's the way I would do it.  It seems to me that it would simplify a number of things for you.

Comment: @MBraedley Yeah, it would. However, I have them saying things in a different command, and so this way, it says "[Heads Up]" before the message rather than "[Blue Flag]" or something similar. You're right, it would be simpler, but it would also compromise the user experience a bit. Certainly, though, it'd be doable if it needs to be done.

Comment: @GeorgePlatko I can respect that design decision. You might be able to do something like the Heads Up stand riding another stand named uniquely, but that's just complicating things at this point.

Comment: @MBraedley Yeah, that's what I thought. I figured it's be easier just to assign each stand a numerical value in a slot nobody will see anyway. :P

Answer (score 2):

The command itself is completely fine, and works for me:

[image]

Make sure:

- You are within range of the ArmorStand that is actually executing the command. If you have multiple ArmorStands with 0 rotation (likely, as they spawn like that by default) the output will only show the result of the ArmorStand that happens to execute last, which may not be in range.
- You actually have a hasBanner score of 0. The default score for an objective is unassigned, not 0, so make sure it's being set to 0 somewhere.
- You are not on blue team.

Comment: Woah, sorry I didn't see this! That's 2 people that say it's operator error, then. I'm away from my worlds right now, but I'll look over your suggestions ASAP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is natural behavior if nothing was found. According to [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Testfor#testfor) wiki page, the `testfor` command fails if no entities match the selector. It appears that your command block is working properly.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - if my command is working properly, then why isn't it doing what I wrote the command for? What do I need to change in order to accomplish the task at hand?

Comment: That's just how it works for some reason. It says it failed to execute the command, but what it means is that the command failed to find anything. The last time the command was run, was there anything it should have found?

Comment: Yeah. Like I said in the question, it was supposed to find me -The armor stand had the correct rotation, `0`,  I wasn't on the blue team, I had a `hasBanner` score of `0`, and I was within 2 blocks of the armor stand. The question isn't why is this specific error coming up, it's _why is there an error at all, if everything was set up according to the command?_

Comment: @GeorgePlatko also it might make it easier to put the armor stands on the relevant teams instead of using rotations.

Comment: ...I can't believe I dodn't think of that. You're toally right. Still, I wonder why this one doesn't work.